# Background image distorted on mobile

Tags: html, css, background-image

So I've seen other people posting about similar problems and I've tried their solutions but none of them have worked.

On desktop, the header background image works perfectly. Even when I resize the window to that of a mobile size, it works. But when I load it on an actual mobile device, the background image doesn't show up. I've discovered that if I remove the `background-position: center center;`, the background image does show up on mobile, but it's distorted.

So, my question is: how can I make the background image show up on mobile without it looking distorted.

My CSS for the `header` container in question is:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../img/header-background.jpg);
    position: relative;
}
```

You can see it in action at: http://coledavidson103.github.io/davidsoncreative/.

Again, the problem only presents itself on a mobile device. It doesn't even happen when I use Inspector to emulate a mobile device.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the problem when I include `background-position: center center`. You'll notice that the image doesn't show up.
[image: Screenshot: with background-position]

Here is a screenshot of the problem with `background-position` is not included. You'll notice the image is distorted.

[image: Screenshot: without background-position]

Comment: It's buggy behaviour with iOS (check the "Known issues") : http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts.

Comment: I'm using Android, not iOS, and I'm still seeing it.

Comment: Looks alright on my phone with Gingerbread (quite ancient). Maybe you could add a screenshot.

Comment: I have added screenshots above.

Comment: Any ideas on how to stop the distortion?

Answer (score 0):

change `background-size: cover` to `background-size:100% 100%`.

Comment: That doesn't work because it will distort the image. It will stretch the dimensions of the image to the dimensions of the window, which will distort it.

Comment: did you set the `viewport`?

Comment: Yes, in the `head` section of my HTML:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: the header background-image appears partially because of `background-size: cover` when i view it on my android phone. where do you see the distortion coming from?

Comment: I have added screenshots above.